# C - strcmp segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

Hello I am new to programming in C. I am trying to learn how to use function. My program run well without arguments but when I add argument e.g. select, select row I get segmentation fault 11. Please can you help where is problem, cause I don't have any errors or warning while I am debugging my program. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int Select(int function)
{
    if (function == 0)
        printf("row");
    else if (function == 1)
        printf("column");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,function;
    for (i = 1; i <= argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--help") == 0)
        {
            printf("Help");
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "select") == 0)
        {
            printf("Select");
            for (j = 2; j <= argc; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(argv[j], "row") == 0)
                {   function = 0;
                    Select(0);
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[j], "column") == 0)
                {   function = 1;
                    Select(1);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a debugger could help to figure out that `argv[i]` and `argv[j]` both will become `NULL` and be passed to `strcmp`.

Comment: "I don't have any errors or warning while I am debugging my program" -- Welcome to the world of C.

Comment: shouldn't it be `for (j = i; j < argc; j++)`? The 2 makes no sense there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
        for (j = 2; j <= argc; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[j], "row") == 0)
```

C has 0-based arrays. Instead do:

```
        for (j = 2; j < argc; j++)
```

If argc says there are 2 items, then that means slots [0] and [1]

Nearly always for loops should go from `0` to `N - 1`

Alternatively, you can iterate without argc, since the last slot of the array is NULL.

```
while(argv[i] != 0) {
    // do stuff

    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please change your for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= argc; i++)
```

To

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
```

The same applies to the j for loop.

argc is the total number to the input arguments. argv[argc] is null.

Comment: Oops I edited your answer instead of mine, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Valid values for indexes into argv are 0 to argc - 1, like other C style arrays. argv[0] will be the name of the executable, and argv[1] onwards contains the command line arguments.

Your loops should just use `i < argc` and `j < argc` as conditions, as a result.